# Problems with Xen installation

Tags: linux, installation, centos, xen

I have CentOS 5.4 installed.
Now I'm trying to install Xen with out connecting to Internet (I have any driver for modem, so I search on Inernet only from Windows).
All I have are 7 installation disks.
First I done was to find kind of some add/remove programs wizard but it needed connection to Inernet.
Second I try was to find Xen rpm on all disks and install it. But I fell on some dependency of some dependency.
Third I attempted was to boot from first disk and do upgrade, but also it was unsuccessfully...
So my question is: is there some way to install Xen from CentOS installation disks with out network?

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: I found way that described here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questi...ng-dvd-806913/, but I get errors like: "failure: CentOS/xen-libs-3.0.3-94.el5.x86_64.rpm from c5-media:" at the end of the process. I tried three first disks, and I think that I will have same errors with four other. Any one know how to install some thing from CentOS disks?

Comment: Here is the error of package manager: 
http://www.4shared.com/document/T3gOtoKG/Error.html , and here is the list of /media/CentOS_5.4_Final/CentOS: http://www.4shared.com/document/d0DciW69/media--CentOS_54_Final--CentOS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!
For get this working I coppied all rpm's from all 7 discs to /repository/CentOS that I was created before that, I summed all contents of TRANS.TBL files from all discs in CentOS directory to one file and saved it in /repository/CentOS/TRANS.TBL, after this I put the importest directory named repodata from first disc (/media/CentOS_5.4_Final/repodata) to /repository/repodata
After that I coppied CentOS-Media.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d to, for instance: CentOS-Local.repo and set baseurl to: baseurl=file:///repository/
Only to /repository/ not to /repository/CentOS/ or /repository/repodata
The last thing was to disable all other repositories like it was described here before.
This is the only way to get it working I thing, because when yum not find some dependency on current cd disc, it throw error instead of require following disc.